# Undo selection of points on canvas

Tags: python, events, canvas, matplotlib

I'm having a little trouble currently with getting some points on a plot to disappear.

Relevant snippet of code

```
for i in range(len(Ray)):
    #ax1.plot(Ray[i], maxI_alongL_lst[Ray[i]], 'x', c = "r")  
    lab = ax1.annotate('R' + str(i+1), xy=(0,0), xytext=(Ray[i], maxI_alongL_lst[Ray[i]] + 50))
    print(lab)

if event.button == 1:
    lab
    plt.draw()
if event.button == 3: 
    #lab = ax1.annotate('R' + str(i+1), xy=(0,0), xytext=(Ray[i], maxI_alongL_lst[Ray[i]] + 50))
    lab.set_visible(False)
    #plt.draw()
```

When I left click the plot, something is appended to Ray, and the plot is annotated. When i right click, something is removed from Ray. I'd also like the right click to remove the relevant annotation (undo, basically).
The code isn;t exactly right, but I had to post something before the internet was switched off (lol).

Many thanks,
O

Comment: please post a minimal working example of the code

Comment: Done. Hope it's enough. Thanks